# Why does Accumulated cost fail with 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'bandCount'?

Tags: pyqgis, saga

When using the function Accumulated cost (isotropic) from the SAGA algorithms in QGIS i get the following error message:

> An error has occurred while executing Python code:
>
> AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'bandCount' 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/AlgorithmDialog.py",
>   line 249, in accept
>       msg = self.alg._checkParameterValuesBeforeExecuting()   File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line
>   233, in _checkParameterValuesBeforeExecuting
>       return self.checkParameterValuesBeforeExecuting()   File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/saga/SagaAlgorithm212.py",
>   line 343, in checkParameterValuesBeforeExecuting
>       if layer.bandCount() > 1: AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'bandCount'
>
> Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) [GCC 5.4.0
>   20160609]  QGIS version: 2.18.0 Las Palmas, b7fe4bb2

I run QGIS on ubuntu. Any ideas on how to solve this? Should i file a bug report, if so where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raster layers have bands. The algorithm input is named "grid" - so I'd assume the tool should only accept rasters. If you used a raster and still get this error, it seems like you found a bug. If you used a vector, this might still be a bug because it probably shouldn't be possible to select a vector layer as input. (Assuming you used the tool from the toolbox and not from the Python console.)

Comment: yeah I think it only accepts two raster files. I managed to get the same task done with r.cost from GRASS which also accepts vector data as sources.